# What is UI Design Draft? Are UI and UI Design Draft same terms?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, design-patterns

I am new to programming so some people use Design Draft term in their libraries so I am not able to understand what does it mean actually, Are UI and UI design draft same terms or they mean different ? Could anyone elaborate please, your effort will be appreciated

Comment: UI = application user interface. UI Design Draft probably means a draft design of a UI.